# How to add fonts to an arXiv submission?

Tags: fonts, arxiv, texlive-2016

Imagine I'd like to upload something on the arXiv. Currently arXiv only
supports texlive 2016. As a consequence the version on my own computer is
also texlive 2016. This version of texlive does not comprise STIX2 fonts.

1. What is the best way for me to work locally on my computer with STIX2 fonts? (One easy solution is: install the latest version of texlive but this is not what I want to do)
2. How do I bundle my submission with the STIX2 fonts to the arXiv?

Comment: can't you simply use stix1 in the arxiv version?

Comment: I've got the same problem; arXiv doesn't use XeTeX or LuaTeX.